# Getting Remote Exception While trying to Access a webmethod in a webservice in java

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client

When i tried to access a webmethod in Code, Getting remote exception. Complete Stack trace below. The same worked when i tried to push the request using SOAP UI.

```
error: com.bea.xml.XmlException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException; nested exception is:
    com.bea.xml.XmlRuntimeException: 
error: com.bea.xml.XmlException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
    java.rmi.RemoteException: error: com.bea.xml.XmlException:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException; nested exception is:
    com.bea.xml.XmlRuntimeException: 
error: com.bea.xml.XmlException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.XXXX.XXXX.XXX.client.XXX.Service_Stub.webmethod(ServicePort_Stub.java:91)
```

Note : I have tried to acecss one more webmethod and able to send request in my Code.

Answer (score 0):

`IllegalArgumentException`, check your parameters format, I think

Comment: I have checked.. All the input parameters are String.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue. It seems response came in. But in the response one of the value is not comply to the pre defined values. But I wonder why I got remote exception for that.

Thanks for all your support!

Comment: Your `IllegalArgumentException` got wrapped in a `RemoteException.` No surprise there.